# Formatting timestamp in django template

Tags: django, datetime, django-templates

I've got this timestamp:

```
2019-05-16T09:06:39Z
```

I'd like to know how could I format it to something more readable in my django template using date.

This is the field in models.py if it has something to do with this issue

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone_now)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score -1):

You can use django builtin template tag.
Try this

```
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

See the reference link to format as your desired.
Ref: [date template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: not working, i've edited the question adding extra info

Answer (score -1):

Consider `{{ start_date }}` is the date which will be in `2019-05-16T09:06:39Z` format.

To format the date to readable date you need to use date template filer as below.

{{ start_date|date:"D, d M, Y" }}

Reference to the [date filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: not working, i've edited the question adding extra info

Comment: no timestamp is being displayed when accessing the web page

Comment: then you are not properly passing date object to template.